# Convert table to matrix equation

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

my table looks like this:

```
 {975/2048 - 512 y[1] + 256 y[2]},
 {175/128 + 256 y[1] - 512 y[2] + 256 y[3]},
 {4095/2048 + 256 y[2] - 512 y[3] + 256 y[4]},
```

I want to convert it to a matrix equation:

```
A*y=b
```

Do you have some suggestions to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eq = {
     975/2048 - 512 y[1] + 256 y[2],
     175/128 + 256 y[1] - 512 y[2] + 256 y[3],
     4095/2048 + 256 y[2] - 512 y[3] + 256 y[4]} 
 b = -eq /. y[_] -> 0;
 a = Transpose[Table[ D[ eq, y[i]] , {i, 4}]];
 a.Table[ y[i], {i, 4}] == b

 {-512 y[1] + 256 y[2],
   256 y[1] - 512 y[2] + 256 y[3], 
   256 y[2] - 512 y[3] + 256 y[4]} == 
                {-(975/2048), -(175/128), -(4095/2048)}
```

then to solve:

```
sol = LinearSolve[a, b];
```

> {3155/524288, 5335/524288, 4715/524288, 0}

```
(eq /. Table[ y[i] -> sol[[i]] , {i, 4}]) == {0, 0, 0}
```

> True